# Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

This error seems to be quite known on StackOverflow but no post gives me a solution that works in my case. I can't propose buttons or checkboxes in my child elements without getting the error:

> Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

the example is not perfect because it does not yet reproduce exactly the concern I encounter but it already illustrates very well what I want to do and the way I do it : https://codesandbox.io/s/test-uz-713xy

the global goal being to display profiles from a table and to be able to display a pop up to modify the information according to the chosen profile

Comment: where is this error thrown? what does editChild method do?

Comment: `this.state.data.map(function(panel){` resets the `this` of `() => { this.editChild(false);}`, because of the use of `function`.

Comment: thanks @Caramiriel so how can I solve that ? Do you know  ?

Comment: So, does replacing `{ this.state.data.map(function(panel){` with `{ this.state.data.map((panel) => {` work?

Comment: It seems not, I'll make an example on sandbox to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done 2 changes and now your codesandbox example is working fine. I have commented the places where I have made changes in render.

```
     render() {
    let func = this.editChild;   // CHANGE HERE
    return (
      <div className="Profil">
        {this.state.data.map(function(panel) {
          return (
            <div className="cHildContener">
              <h1> Hello my name is {panel.name}</h1>
              <h2> I'm {panel.age} years old</h2>
              <Button
                onClick={() => {
                  func(false); // CHANGE HERE
                }}
              >
                EDIT
              </Button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        {this.state.PopupEdit ? (
          <div className="PopUP">
            <h1>EDIT A CHILD</h1>
            <p>
              I would like display the name of the concerned child, but i don't
              know how to do
            </p>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.firstname}
              onChange={this.onFieldChange("firstname").bind(this)}
              placeholder="children new name"
              required
            />
            />
            <input
              className="slave"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.age}
              onChange={this.onFieldChange("age").bind(this)}
              placeholder="children age"
              required
            />
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                this.editChild(true);
              }}
            >
              EDIT
            </Button>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I edited my question to make it more understandable. like than i can prove that "this.state && this.state.data" works

Comment: I'm sorry, but my problem remains the same. I pressed too fast enter.

Comment: ok. can you post the code of `editChild` function as well or can you post the working snippet on codeSandbox

Comment: i just edit again my question, I will try to make it on Sandbox too to make it easier to understand.

Comment: I have done some changes to as how editChild can be called and declared. You may once try doing that. If it works than fine else may be I can see the code on codeSandbox and try to figure out. Thanks

Comment: I've created an example on codesandbox to make the whole thing more relevant, but I still have a few problems with it. I work on IT to make the perfect exemple of my situation.

Comment: I have made 2 changes and now your code sandbox example works perfect. I have edited 2 places in render function. I have edited the code in my answer. You can try that once

Comment: Thanks a lot mate !!! that's work well on my side too.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this same issue but this time with a Checkbox ? I just edit my exemple on CodeSandBox : https://codesandbox.io/s/test-uz-713xy

Comment: Ok sure I will try.. can you raise a question on stackoverflow and I will give you the updated as answer as the file code could be large and won't come in comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62773830/cannot-read-property-data-of-undefined-with-checkboxs-in-child-elements thanks again for your help